# Partial Mock in Laravel - method not exists

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I've a class that calls one method from another

```
class eppConnection()
{
    public function request($xml) 
    {
        $result = $this->makeRequest($xml)
    }

    private function makeRequest($xml) 
    {

    }
}
```

I want to simulate response from `makeRequest` and do a partial mock

```
$mock = $this->partialMock('EppConnection', function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('sendRequest')`
         ....
}
```

Next, I make class from DI and call methods

```
$eppConnection = app()->make('EppConnection');
$requestResult = $eppConnection->sendRequest('text') // This works
$requestResult = $eppConnection->request('text') // This not
```

method `request` raises an error `Method Mockery_0__EppConnection::request() does not exist on this mock object`

I've no idea why, because I do a partial mock, so documentaion says "The methods that are not mocked will be executed normally when called".

Please point me, why it happens and how to fix.